# javascript load new url in div?

Tags: javascript, html

I got this code, to simple to have any errors and still... 
I have a nav, where the onclick calls for clicker(nodenr) what should load an external site in an div.

```
function clicker(nodenr) {
    var url=links[nodenr];
    console.log(nodenr);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', ''+url+'', true);
    //request.open('GET', ''url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
        if(request.status == 200) {
            console.log("hello");
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "Service not loading.";
        }
    }
};
```

}

What basic error have I made? Please correct me. :)

Comment: Well, what's your problem actually?

Comment: You cannot access another site from ajax requests, for security reasons. The remote side should return the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but pasting your original question into Google shows so many results that you can work with. You could use jQuery.load() which will probably fit your needs here.

Comment: If you're trying to request data from a server other than yours you'll be blocked and you'll get `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN POLICY RESTRICTION` error unless this server sends `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN: *` header. If you're trying to get data from the same server thren, do you store the nav links in the `links` variable ? and is `links` variable global ?

Comment: Try setting  response type  as  request.responseType = 'text'